# how to sort, filter json data in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a json array that i get back from an api (sample below) . say I want to sort the data based on age, and also select first 5 of them, how can I do this in ruby?

```
[  
    {"name":"Richard", "email":"r@gmail.com", "age" : "32"},  
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "age" : "52"}, 
    ....
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your array

```
arr=[

    {"name"=>"Richard", "email"=>"r@gmail.com", "age" => "32"},
    {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age" => "52"},
    {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age" => "21"},
    {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age" => "58"},
    {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age" => "45"},
    {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age" => "67"},
    {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age" => "92"}
]
```

Code

```
p arr.sort_by{|h|h['age']}.first(5)
#=>[{"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age"=>"21"}, {"name"=>"Richard", "email"=>"r@gmail.com", "age"=>"32"}, {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age"=>"45"}, {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age"=>"52"}, {"name"=>"Bob", "email"=>"bob32@gmail.com", "age"=>"58"}]
```